# How can I parameterize Mixins in python, without calling their constructor explicitly?

Tags: python, mixins

I want to use Mixins more in python and like the pattern of:

```
class Person:
  [...]

class Greetable:
  greeting: str

  def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    super().__init(*args, **kwargs)
    ... greeting related setup

  def greet(self):
    print(f"{self.greeting} sir or madam!")

class Sailor(Greetable, Person):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.greeting = "Ahoy"

>>> Sailor().greet()
"Ahoy sir or madam!"
```

But I have yet to crack the problem of having parameterized mixins. In my job I see a lot of explicit `__init__` calls to super classes alá

```
class A(B, FloorMixin):
  def __init__(desk, chair, floor):
    B.__init__(self, desk, chair)
    FloorMixin.__init__(floor)
```

I see the use in breaking up the parameters and distributing them explicitely, but I would like to keep the "passthrough" property the `__init__` of the above Mixin example has.

I could only think of having all arguments to the Mixin as specific keyword arguments, which get `pop`'ed out of the `**kwargs` parameter or only relying on fields being present in the mixin and having to set them before, which would turn the last example into:

```
class A(FloorMixin, B):
  def __init__(desk, chair, floor):
    self._floor = floor  # FloorMixin expects a _floor attribute

    super().__init__(desk, chair)
```

Comment: That is essentially the advice laid out in [Python's super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/): Extract the arguments that you will handle, and pass the rest on. (The same advice is reiterated in the conclusion to https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/, which turns out not to be  a rebuttal so much as additional clarification on how to use `super` correctly.)

Comment: @chepner Does that mean, that Mixins should not call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` blindly, because in that case constructors could be called multiple times?

Comment: They will not be called multiple times, because each class only appears in the method resolution order once. They should use `super` like any other class.

Comment: If you are inheriting from a class that uses `super`, you should also use `super`. If you are inheriting from a class that does *not* use `super`, then nothing that inherits from you should use `super` either, unless you follow the advice for inheriting from non-cooperative classes in PSCS.

Answer (score 4):

The key to using `super` properly is that every class involved in the hierarchy should assume that everyone else will also call `super`. That's true for every class except `object`, which is always the root class in any inheritance hierarchy.

For your example

```
class A(B, FloorMixin):
  def __init__(self, desk, chair, floor):
    B.__init__(self, desk, chair)
    FloorMixin.__init__(floor)
```

that means that `A`, `B`, and `FloorMixin` should all calling `super().__init__`, and you should use keyword arguments when instantiating `A` so that there are no ordering-based conflicts.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, desk, chair, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Do stuff with desk and chair

class FloorMixin:
    def __init__(self, floor, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Do stuff with floor

class A(B, FloorMixin):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # If there's nothing else to do, you don't
        # even need to define A.__init__

# With keyword arguments, order doesn't matter
# Each __init__ will find the arguments it needs
# and pass on the rest
a = A(floor="...", chair="...", desk="...")
```

The method resolution order for `A` is `[A, B, FloorMixin, object]`, so each call to `super().__init__` calls `__init__` from the next class in line. `A.__init__` calls `B.__init__`, which calls `FloorMixin.__init__`, which calls `object.__init__`. Importantly, note that this means that at *runtime*, `B.__init__` calls `__init__` of a class that the author of `B` may not even have known about. That's why it's important to accept unexpected keyword arguments and to pass them on.

Comment: Does this preclude me from writing `a = A(floor_obj, chair_obj, desk_obj)`, i. e. forcing me to call functions with kwargs explicitly?

Comment: As written, yes.  You can define `A.__init__` with `def __init__(self, floor, chair, desk, **kwargs)` (or whatever order you prefer), then call `super().__init__(floor=floor, chair=chair, desk=desk, **kwargs)`. The convention of only using names for parameters that your class introduces, though, is a bit cleaner, IMO.